# Mod Rewrite using .htaccess to change from .html to clean structure

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to clean up the URLs on my website.

My structure is currently

lifestrology.com/113-matt-barnes.html

But I need it to be:

lifestrology.com/title-of-gallery/name-of-photo

My current rewrite structure is:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

#Please edit this part to match your website
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lifestrology.com/$
#RewriteRule (.*) http://lifestrology.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#Please do not edit anything underneath.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} msg=(.+)
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html?$ view.php?id=$1&msg=%1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html?$ view.php?id=$1 [NC]
```

Can someone help me with fixing the structure of my urls to make them lifestrology.com/title-of-gallery/name-of-photo ? Also can this be fixed to work with the current items already on my website?

Comment: Does your `view.php` script know how to render a page given a title of a gallery and the name of a photo? Otherwise, the new structure isn't going to work.

Comment: I'm not sure. If you guys have skype or something I can show you

Comment: What I mean is, can you invoke the script like `view.php?title=title-of-gallery&name=name-of-photo`, or something similar

Comment: Umm.. I'm not sure. I contacted you on twitter. Can we chat?

Comment: @JonLin I'm pretty sure it's possible but I didn't write this script. I paid for it to be custom made but the developer is no longer available to assist me. I've read a bunch of tutorials but I'm pulling my hair out at this point trying to figure out how to take care of this.

Comment: Hey @JonLin can you help? I really need it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.html [L]
```

and for any additional slash:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```

after tailoring the code above to suit your custom needs.

Hope it helps.

Comment: do I replace something in the .htaccess file or add this?

Comment: You put these lines below the "RewriteEngine on". Also note that for ANY slash you wanna see in your link, you have to add an extra couple of "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]"

Comment: It didnt work. Can you make the complete .htaccess info I need to use instead of the current one I have now?